# multiple columns in data table kibana

Tags: kibana

I have a data table visualization in Kibana where I show UserName and the number of actions by that username.

But, I would also like to add additional columns to the table:

```
Username | Firstname | Lastname | email | #actions |
```

How can I do this?

Also, I added the Firstname, Lastname, email fields only recently so the old data does not have these fields.

How can make the table in this case?

Comment: It's hard to understand what the problem, you need to create the visualisation like all datatable, documents without specific field will show as null or empty string